# How do 'no code' websites publish webpages for each user?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, server, subdomain

I'm wondering how 'no code' sites are able to host a unique website (defined by a subdomain) for each of their users, and have the the html and content updated when the user makes changes.

Are they running some form of 'npm run build && deploy_to_subdomain' every single time a change is made?  How in the world would that work, since you can only upload 1 real build for a subdomain anyhow (because the real domain is the same)? Am I misunderstanding something?

The only other option I can think of is saving the changes to a database, and then just calling it & generating html when you hit the page. (Or vice versa) But that doesn't make sense and would be very slow.

Using React, Node.js, and Heroku if that matters.

Comment: Check out this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain

Comment: @code You are fantastic, upvoted and thank you very much.